# How to apply a CSS style dynamically using React JS?

Tags: css, reactjs

I would like to know how to apply CSS dynamically to all the elements in a page that belong to a CSS class in React JS?
Currently I am using the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.my-paragraph-class').forEach(function (x: any) {
  x.style.fontSize = `${data.value}%`;
});
```

It works but I would like to know if there is a more efficient way instead of using `document.querySelectorAll`?

Also when the page loads new text, document.querySelectorAll has to be called again after the text loads, which is not ideal. I would like to know how to persist the modified CSS changes when new text is loaded dynamically?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For applying a static font size to a class you shouldn’t have to use JavaScript at all.

In your css file just do:

```
.my-paragraph-class: {
 font-size: 10rem || whatever;
}
```

To dynamically add styling you could use a CSS in JS tool like styled components. For styled components you would import styled components and then write a code outside of your react function like this:

```
const StyledParagraph = styled.p`
 font-size: 10rem || ${props => props.fontSize}
`
```

In your JSX you would do something like:

```
 <StyledParagraph fontSize=“10rem”> Filler Text </StyledParagraph>
```

Comment: Thank you! @Kyle currently my component has a font size selector that increases or decreases the font size according to user selection. I will give it a try passing the font size as a parameter on the component that contains the paragraphs.